# Duplicate Core Data objects created in RestKit 0.20.2

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I'm running into an issue where I'm getting duplicate writes to my SQLite database every time I perform a mapping operation in RestKit 0.20.2.  I've looked online pretty extensively and can't seem to find a duplicate issue to what I'm experiencing—all of the similar problems I've seen center around using RestKit for everything, while I'm using RestKit just for the mapping and database operations, as I'm doing the network aspect in another library.

I have a unique `identificationAttribute` property set (the tweet ID) and am using a `managedObjectCache` initialized with `RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache`; however, every time I perform a mapping operation, I'm getting duplicates across the board on everything.  The library I'm using for the network side (STTwitter) returns the JSON as an array, so I iterate through each object in the array.  Is there some other operation I'm supposed to be performing? I was under the impression that RestKit compares the `identificationAttribute` property specified in mapped objects to what's already in the SQLite database before doing any insertions.  I wasn't encountering this issue when I used it for everything in another project, using `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`.

Here's how I set up the model:

```
-(void)setup
{
self.objectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

[self.objectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FoodTruckxxx.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"Setting up store at %@", path);
[self.objectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path
                          fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil
                               withConfiguration:nil
                                         options:self.optionsForSQLiteStore
                                           error:nil];

[self.objectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

self.objectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:self.objectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
}
```

and here's how I perform the mapping operation:

```
-(void)performMapping
{
int i = 0;
while (i < self.localCopyOfAllStatuses.count)
{
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[FoodTruckDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [ObjectMappings FoodTruckArticleMapping];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FoodTruck" inManagedObjectContext:store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
    RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *mappingDS = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext cache:store.managedObjectCache];

    //assign new array to contain to just one object at a time and iterate through it
    NSArray *justOneStatus = [self.localCopyOfAllStatuses objectAtIndex:i];
    RKMappingOperation *operation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:justOneStatus destinationObject:newManagedObject mapping:mapping];
    operation.dataSource = mappingDS;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [operation performMapping:&error];
    [store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext save:&error];
    [store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error];
    i++;
}
}
```

And here is the mapping:

```
+(RKEntityMapping *)FoodTruckArticleMapping
{
RKEntityMapping *jsonMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"FoodTruck" inManagedObjectStore:[[FoodTruckDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore]];
jsonMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"tweetID"];

[jsonMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"text": @"tweet", @"user.screen_name": @"foodTruckName", @"created_at": @"timeStamp", @"id": @"tweetID"}];

return jsonMapping;
}
```

And [here](http://pastebin.com/ZXCaUjq5) is a complete operation from my log.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're explicitly creating managed object instances in your loop. Why don't you give RestKit the entire JSON response and let it do all of the mapping and object creation?

Comment: Wain- I do give it the JSON response and the mapping in `RKMappingOperation`, right? The `sourceObject` is a JSON response and `mapping` is my `RKEntityMapping`.  What would I put for `destinationObject` in that call, then, other than a `NSManagedObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the answer to this question [on the RestKit Google Group board](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/restkit/FJxI0pDY3Wg/pYoVKLNCz9UJ) (which I verified worked), the solution was to not create a `NSManagedObject` and to assign `nil` to `destinationObject` in my `RKMappingOperation` declaration.  Below is the correct code for this method, and the answer to my initial question:

```
-(void)performMapping
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < self.localCopyOfAllStatuses.count)
    {
        RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[FoodTruckDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
        RKEntityMapping *mapping = [ObjectMappings FoodTruckArticleMapping];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FoodTruck" inManagedObjectContext:store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
        RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *mappingDS = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext cache:store.managedObjectCache];

        //assign new array to contain to just one object at a time and iterate through it
        NSArray *justOneStatus = [self.localCopyOfAllStatuses objectAtIndex:i];
        RKMappingOperation *operation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:justOneStatus destinationObject:nil mapping:mapping];
        operation.dataSource = mappingDS;
        NSError *error = nil;
        [operation performMapping:&error];
        [store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext save:&error];
        [store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error];
        i++;
    }
}
```

However, it was also suggested in the RestKit Google Group link that I implement `RKMapperOperation` instead of `RKMappingOperation,` as it then saves me the trouble of iterating through my array of JSON responses.  This is what I eventually went with, which I present for the sake of efficiency and better use of RestKit:

```
-(void)performMapping
{
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[FoodTruckDataModel sharedDataModel] objectStore];
    RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *mappingDS = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext cache:store.managedObjectCache];
    RKMapperOperation *mapperOperation = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:self.localCopyOfAllStatuses mappingsDictionary:@{ [NSNull null]: [ObjectMappings FoodTruckArticleMapping] }];
    mapperOperation.mappingOperationDataSource = mappingDS;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [mapperOperation execute:&error];
    [store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext save:&error];
    [store.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error];
}
```

Comment: What is the return you give for [ObjectMappings FoodTruckArticleMapping], is that just a dictionary of the maps, or a Mapper Object which will contain the Relationship mappings etc... This is one of the few parts im struggling to get my head around.

Comment: `[ObjectMappings FoodTruckArticleMapping]` is a class method that instantiates and returns a `RKEntityMapping` object initialized with, among other things, a dictionary of mappings.  Let me know if you need more help; I could put some code up on Pastebin or Gist for you.

Comment: If you could show me your ObjectMappings class that would be great, this makes more sense to me now, if i am understanding this correctly then inside the dictionary of mappings, you could put another RKEntityMapping if you have nested Entities.

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/dgFCjyxf.  I haven't done nested entities, but there should be plenty of examples of that out there.  I also found the RestKit unit tests extremely helpful—you can find them in their GitHub repo.

Comment: Thanks for the codesnip, thats pretty much exactly what i have now, although why are you calling save: and saveToPersistentStore, isnt one the default and the second the RK version but will write to SQL file. Have been speaking with BlakeWatter, who wrote RK and he's shown me the UT classes, i think its working apart from the Nested Elements, just a hunch....Unable to find nesting value for attribute '<RK_NESTING_ATTRIBUTE>'

Comment: Sorry, just saw this—had to call both (it seemed) for writing to take place successfully.  It was a while ago when I worked on this project.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're explicitly creating managed object instances in your loop so RestKit doesn't have an opportunity to check for duplicates. Instead, you should give RestKit the entire JSON response and let it do all of the mapping and object creation.

To achieve this, look at using [`RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation.html). This operation allows you to specify the managed object context, the mappings and the entire response content (you don't explicitly do any looping). This gives RestKit all of the information it needs to check for duplicates.

Something along the lines of:

```
RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation *responseMapperOperation = [[RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation alloc] initWithRequest:self.request
                                                                                                                         response:self.response
                                                                                                                             data:self.responseData
                                                                                                              responseDescriptors:self.responseDescriptors];
responseMapperOperation.mapperDelegate = self;
responseMapperOperation.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
responseMapperOperation.managedObjectCache = self.managedObjectCache;

[responseMapperOperation setDidFinishMappingBlock:^(RKMappingResult *mappingResult, NSError *responseMappingError) {

    // use the mappingResult which contains the received objects

}];
```

Add the responseMapperOperation to a queue to execute.

Be sure to import the required RestKit classes.

Comment: Wain- thanks a lot for the response. It'll be a day or two before I can check it out.

Comment: Wain- do you have any suggestions as to how I might implement it in my code? Also, when I try and use it directly, as in `RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation *rkTest = [[RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation alloc] init];` it says it's an unknown type name.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding that—would you prefer I mark it as the answer now or wait until I've had time to implement it?

Comment: So, in looking at your code example and the RestKit docs, the `RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation` initializer method seems to need `NSURLRequest` and `NSHTTPURLResponse` objects...as stated in the question, I'm using another library (STTwitter) to perform all the REST operations, so I'm just handing RestKit a JSON array.  Is there something I'm missing, or is there a way to make this class work with that?

Comment: I was hoping your library ave more access than it does. RestKit needs access to the URLs in order to process the JSON in terms of mappings and configured fetch requests. There's a lot that goes into performMappingOnResponseWithCompletionBlock:. You'd need to copy the source code for that and modify. But the library you're using doesn't even give you the URLs...

Comment: Wain- thanks for all your help, you were very close on the part about not giving RestKit managed object instances.  Please see my answer.